# Is "mother tongue" exactly the same as "native language"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Someone just told me "mother tongue" is exactly the same as "native language".
I may be wrong, but I think the first one is not a good translation.

Am I wrong?

Comment: What did you think was the difference? And what does "the first one is not a good translation (thanks google translate)" mean?

Comment: Google translate => If you try to translate from French "Langue maternelle" to English, you get "Mother tongue" => If you try to translate from English "Native language" to French, you get "Langue maternelle". Two differents results.

Comment: From what you say, and i have just confirmed it, i infer that Google Translate believes that "mother tongue" _is_ exactly the same as "native language". I still believe your question needs some editing. One item could be to include the details you just gave about GT.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Mother tongue" and "native language" are set phrases that both refer to the language one has started learning from birth. One generally associates "mother" with "tongue" and "native" with "language" but it is sometimes found the other way round. "Language" and "tongue" are here synonyms.

I would say "mother" or "native" is not identical though. When using "native" the reference is more to the country/nation. When using "mother" the reference is to the parent (mother or father), which gives it a warmth and personal relationship that the word "native" doesn't have.

I've found a sentence that I think can explain what I mean about "native" and "mother" although native being used here in association with country:

> As a parent living far from my native country I have often experienced
>   the fear that my children would not learn their mother language well.

In this [whole text](http://www.fountainmagazine.com/Issue/detail/Mother-Tongue-The-Language-of-Heart-and-Mind) the use of "mother tongue" is not identical and I doubt the person who wrote it would have used "native language" (or "native tongue") where she used "mother language".

Comment: I don't think 'indifferent' means what you expect it to mean. It means 'you don't care one way or the other. Rather than litotes, just use '... are not identical though'.

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks, you have perfectly understood what I meant. English not being my native language my tongue sometimes slips.

Comment: An edit changing the meaning of my answer had been made by community. I reverted to my original answer and if anyone disagrees they should do it in a comment and we can discuss as civilised people.

Comment: I thought that edit wasn't great, but I believe there was only a typo, "form birth"; however users with low rep cannot edit posts unless six characters or more have been changed, and hence the rewording. I wouldn't "blame" the anonymous editor but the users who allowed the edit to go through. See [my meta  post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6811/inaccurate-edits-that-pass-through-the-review-net) on the topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: the edit was about reverting "from birth" to "as a child" which changed the entire meaning - and which I consider as false in the context of my  answer.  Babies and children are entirely different entities. We learn one language from birth (and that starts in the mother's womb, we know babies hear sounds in the womb that begin to shape their sense of language), as children we can learn lots of languages, it is an entirely different process of learning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  And I agree with you if anyone are to blame it is those long standing users who approved an edit that changed the meaning of the answer.

Comment: You don't have to justify why you thought the edit was harmful, when I saw it yesterday I felt slightly uneasy. I don't think it invalidated your answer, but it is an *inaccurate* observation. Why not post an answer on meta question? You sound pretty much upset, let off steam there. :)

Comment: Laure, to me the meaning is not changed at all. There has been a lot of research lately showing that children under one year old have some very subtle language influences on them. Which is to say that before the research, people thought that any substantive language occurs after a year, and that the research only found _subtle_ affects. 'From birth' or 'as a child' can hardly ever be considered very different (as opposed to learning later in school or as an adult immigrant). So the community edit is really inconsequential.

Comment: I believe "native" refers more to where or what you're born into than to a country or nation. So I'd say the meaning of "native language" would be more like the language you were "born into" (i.e., what you hear and speak mostly since you've been born). If, for example, you were born and grew up in a country but not speak its language often as a child (as sometimes expats' children who are sent to English or other language schools), that country's language would not be your native language, despite you possibly having lived their your whole life.

Answer (score 7):

Multilingualism adds a questionable level of complexity to the established equations.If we were to define the terms based on today's demography then it sure is relevant to consider the following. And FYKI [monolingualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolingualism) is a [thing](http://www.olce.org/pdfs/BEWL/EscamillaPresentationpdf.pdf) of the [past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age).

Wiki states:

> "One can have two or more native languages, thus being a native
>   bilingual or indeed multilingual. The order in which these languages
>   are learned is not necessarily the order of proficiency. For instance,
>   a French-speaking couple might have a daughter who learned French
>   first, then English; but if she were to grow up in an English-speaking
>   country, she would likely be most proficient in English."

Wiki defines the concerned terms by establishing a differential approach.

Defining mother tongue:

```
Based on origin: the language(s) one learned first (the language(s) in which one has
established the first long-lasting verbal contacts).
Based on internal identification: the language(s) one identifies with/as a speaker
of;
Based on external identification: the language(s) one is identified with/as a
speaker of, by others.
Based on competence: the language(s) one knows best.
Based on function: the language(s) one uses most.
```

A native speaker is defined according to the guidelines that:

```
The individual acquired the language in early childhood
The individual has intuitive knowledge of the language
The individual is able to produce fluent, spontaneous discourse
The individual is competent in communication
The individual identifies with or is identified by a language community
The individual does not have a foreign accent
```

Comment: To be clear, do you intend your answer to be the quotations, or the declaration that the quoted sources are incorrect? I don't know whether to up- or down-vote...

Comment: Quoted sources are correct. Well, these are the points outlined in the Wiki which I happen to agree upon. Feel free to cast your up-vote. (:

Answer (score 6):

`Mother tongue` and `Native language` have similar, meanings and are often actually interchangeable, however there is a subtle difference.

`Native language` refers to the language of the area the person grows up in.  For example, growing up in the United States, your `native language` would be English.  It's the language used every day everywhere you go by the vast majority of the people there.

`Mother tongue` refers to the language of the family you grew up in.  The language your parents spoke in the house, or to each other out-and-about if applicable.  Often, parents will use the same language as that of the region (parents in the U.S. speaking English) however it can differ.  Take for example a family of immigrants from Mexico to the United States.  In their house and with family/friends they may use Spanish.  But at school, restaurants, stores, etc they would use English.  In this case, the `native language` is English and the `mother tongue` is Spanish.

Typically, the two will refer to the same language, in which case they are interchangeable; however, in some cases they may differ.

Answer (score 4):

As someone growing up in a Malaysian-Chinese household, I always consider my mother tongues to be the various Chinese dialects while my native languages are Malay (Bahasa Malaysia) and English, since the latter two I began learning concurrently and have been ever since. So for me, there are very distinctive, though as many of you have pointed out, subtle differences between the two.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This has the makings of a good answer; could you expand on what the "subtle differences" are? How do you determine which language is "mother tongue" vs "native language"? At the moment, it's not much more than an anecdote, unfortunately.

Comment: Is this a common understanding or just your own? Can you provide any evidence either way?

Answer (score 0):

*Mother tongue* and *native language* mean the same thing.  Both words share an etymology.  I missed this fact earlier and my thanks to the sharp-eyed commenters who caught it.

Comment: So this is the same, but only in countries which origins are Latin? (Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: The are the same in English-speaking countries and, I would imagine, in most other countries where the language has been influenced by Latin.  English, of course, is a Germanic language but has been highly influenced by French and Latin.

Comment: @OlivierPons the meaning is that `mother tongue` and `native language` can mean the same thing because, in English, `tongue` can be used as a synonym for language. This would not be true in a language where people do not use their word for `tongue` the same way.

Comment: There's no play on words in mother tongue. One of the definition of tongues in the OED: *The speech or language of a people or race*

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin It's not really a play on words. Both *tongue* and *lingua* have a common root in PIE which can mean speech, language, or the organ of speech--and it has been historically used for this meaning in English as well as Latin.