# What is the history of the phrase 'mother tongue'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Where does the phrase 'mother tongue' originate from? 
Based on this phrase, in a literal sense is a language deemed to be feminine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "mother tongue" exactly the same as "native language"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146500/is-mother-tongue-exactly-the-same-as-native-language)

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't see the question answering about the history or origin of the phrase, so I'm inclined to give this post the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: That said, Curly, it would help to list what sources you've used. At minimum, what does Wikipedia say about it? After looking at a common source or two, what are your questions about that?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin yes I was at first going to mention it rather put a close vote. I found one suggestion of the origins of the phrase within a few seconds, within [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language).

Comment: I don't understand it that way - I think it refers to the language you were mothered in, just as *school language* would refer to the language you were schooled in.

Comment: When one refers to the "mother land" would that not have something to do as well with the use of  "mother tongue"? I would think one would go hand-in-hand with the other. Also, that begs the question, where does "mother land" originate? is that simply the land from where your mother is originally an inhabitant?

Comment: @JoeBlow *motherland* is different IMO - it's like *motherboard* or *mothership*, i.e. the main one - the one the others are dependent on.

Comment: @Minty agreed with motherboard. According to my findings mothership has to do with whaling and the mothership was the slower of the ships where they stored the meat. That being said, mother land could be defined as the country where one was born. Mother Tongue could be the language one first learned growing up I guess.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following extract from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language) the expression *mother tongue* was first originally used by Catholic monks to refer to local languages which they used to preach in different countries.

> According to ***[Ivan Illich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Illich)*** (philosopher, Roman Catholic priest), ***the term "mother tongue" was first used by Catholic monks to designate a particular language they used, instead of Latin, when they were "speaking from the pulpit"***. That is, the "holy mother the Church" introduced this term and colonies inherited it from Christianity as a part of colonialism.